# Auto insert tag in arbortext editor

Tags: xml

I want to insert certain tags by default. ex: when in insert table tag title should insert by default.I want to do this with out changing DTD.

How i will achive this by editing DCF/FOSI files in arbortext editor.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The answer has already been posted to the adepters mailing list. That is your best place to find Arbortext Help. The PTC Dev Team monitors that list as well as many experienced users. You can sign up at ptcuser.org

For the record, the answer is in the HELP Files.

Consult the "Inserting elements and text automatically" page in the Arbortext Help Center for exact steps.